# Detach JetBrains DataGrip from terminal

Tags: command-line

I recently installed DataGrip from JetBrains, I extracted in `/usr/local/share` and I added into my `~/.zshrc` to execute from the terminal like this

```
DATAGRIP_HOME=/usr/local/share/DataGrip/
export PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin:$DATAGRIP_HOME:$DATAGRIP_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME:$ACTIVATOR:$ACTIVATOR/bin:$SCALA:$SCALA/bin:$TMUXIFIER:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Every time I execute datagrip.sh the proccess keep attached into the terminal and I get all the log of the application

which is the way to detach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it with (replace `<command>` with the command you use to run it):

```
<command> & disown
```

Comment: Glad that I could be of help!